# Different length listed format to R Dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am using `CountsEPPM` to do some sample problems. This package use `data` as listed format.

```
library(CountsEPPM)
data("herons.group")
herons.group
$group
[1]  Adult     Immature
Levels:  Adult  Immature

$number.attempts
$number.attempts[[1]]
 [1] 0 5 2 1 1 1 0 2 0 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1

$number.attempts[[2]]
 [1] 0 2 2 1 5 1 2 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

I am using the following code to convert the listed format to dataframe. It ended up with an error.

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(herons.group, as.data.frame))
Error in data.frame(c(0, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 25, 26
```

The head of the dataframe would be like:

```
  group number.attempts
1 Adult               0
2 Adult               5
3 Adult               2
4 Adult               1
5 Adult               1
6 Adult               1
```

The tail:

```
      group number.attempts
46 Immature               0
47 Immature               0
48 Immature               0
49 Immature               0
50 Immature               0
51 Immature               1
```

Comment: The elements of the list herons.group have different lengths. Data.frames are the tabular version of lists whose elements have all the same length. Not sure what you were expecting as output.

Comment: I have edited the question for a better flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that I understood the structure of the data:

```
data.frame(group = rep(herons.group$group, times = lengths(herons.group$number.attempts)),
           number.attempts = unlist(herons.group$number.attempts))
```

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty, but if you want to use `do.call`, you can do the following

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

i <- length(herons.group$group)

1:i %>% lapply(function(i) { 
    herons.group$number.attempts[[i]] %>% 
        as.data.frame %>% 
        setNames(herons.group$group[i]) %>% 
        gather(group, number.attempts)
}) %>% 
    do.call("rbind", .)
```